# Dojo Calendar: After change, cannot manipulate calendar events

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using `dojox/calendar/Calendar` in my app, using a `dojo/store/JsonRest` store. When moving a calendar entry, it correctly calls the REST URL to update the entry, and receives a successful response which I can see under the network tab of the developer tools in my browser.

However, any item that is moved this way becomes unresponsive. I can see that it has the class `Storing`, so the framework seems to think that the item is still being stored and has not responded.

This is my code in app.js:

```
require(["dojo/ready", "dojox/calendar/Calendar", "dojo/store/JsonRest", "dojo/store/Observable"],
    function (ready, Calendar, JsonRest, Observable) {

        ready(function () {
            var appointmentStore = JsonRest({target: '/api/appointments'});

            var calendar = new Calendar({
                date: new Date(2008, 05, 08),
                dateInterval: "month",
                store: new Observable(appointmentStore),
                startTimeAttr: "start",
                endTimeAttr: "end",
                query: '?activity_type_code=ZD03',
                style: "position:relative;width:800px;height:500px"
            }, "calendar");

        });
    });
```

These are the headers of the response of the XHR request to update the item:

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:877
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Thu, 12 Nov 2015 05:25:08 GMT
Server:WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.6/2015-04-13)
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
```

(I thought at first that the problem is that I did not set the response type to JSON, but even after doing that, it still does not work).

Here is the calendar event div tag that made me think that as far as the calendar is concerned, the update is not complete (because of the presence of the 'Storing' class):

```
<div class="dojoxCalendarEvent dojoxCalendarVertical Storing" onselectstart="return false;" id="dojox_calendar_VerticalRenderer_0" widgetid="dojox_calendar_VerticalRenderer_0" style="z-index: 0; top: 400px; left: 0%; width: 100%; height: 101px; display: block;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had somehow overlooked that there was an error on the console. The problem is that the web service being called in the background does not return the definition of the calendar item / appointment, and the Dojo calendar framework is looking for the begin and end dates in the response. As a result, it is raising an error, and as far as it is concerned, the storing of the item is not complete.